# Decrease of potential by negative charge

Tags: electrostatics, potential, work, potential-energy, voltage

[image]

Initially there is a body $A$. To increase it's potential we give positive charge to it which means we need to do more work to bring a test charge from infinity. Now we bring a negatively charged body near it. Why does the potential of body $A$ decrease due to negatively charged $B$ (why do we need to do less work to bring a test charge from infinity now)?

Comment: I suggest you to read about screened Coulomb potentials, see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric-field_screening#Screened_Coulomb_interactions).

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't answer my question,could you please show the reason with work done example?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not like that we don't have to do less work. Potential does not mean just bringing the unit positive test charge from infinity it actually means work done by an  $EXTERNAL$  agent in bringing a unit positive test charge from infinity to the point where we have to find the potential.

It's negative so it does not mean that we have to do less work the reason is only the force and displacement are in the opposite direction that's it. Still we have to do same amount of work by $PULLING$ the charge opposite to the direction of field to keep the velocity constant or to bring it very slowly as that we have to do with the positive charge with same magnitude.

Okay let's take an example and understand this what I'm trying to say.
So let's assume that the person is with full of energy inside his body and let's assume the case of positive charge so in bringing the positive charge from the infinity the person's body loose the energy and that energy evades out by doing the workdone and now let's take a case where there is negative charge with same magnitude as that of positive charge, so when the person will pull that charge his body will loose same amount of energy and feel same weakness as before that means that much amount of energy got converted in the workdone again. In both the cases the person Is REMOVING energy from his body that means he is doing the same amount work in both the cases.

And in this case you took a negative charge with some different charge magnitude, I mean it's not a unit positive charge so in the calculation of the workdone by an external agent will be:-

$W = \int_∞^r \frac{K q_1 q_2}{x^2} \,dx$

So my answer would be No, we have to do same amount of work as we do for positive charge.

Comment: Then why is the potential of $A$ decreased due to $B$?

Comment: No potential is not decreased potential is workdone in bringing the $UNIT$ $POSITIVE $ $CHARGE$ the thing which you are trying to find with B which is negatively charge is not potential. It's potential energy stored in negatively charged particle.

Comment: Sorry but it is a fact that negative charge when brought near a conductor decreases the potential of that conductor.

Comment: And with this to find potential of the charged particle the procedure only includes two things that is the unit test positive charge and the charge of which you have to find the potential that's it. And I should say that yes the potential will be decreased but not of the charged particle but at the point on which the potential was first created due to the positively charged particle because as soon as you bring the negatively charged particle in the system as well the potential of the negatively charged particle comes out to be negative so at that point the potential will get....

Comment: .....Directly subtracted from the potential created by the positively charged particle. edit:- that's why the potential decreases at that point (or near to the charged particle) because of the influence of negatively charged particle

Comment: The potential of that conductor that means you are trying to say inside or outside of that conductor using the language $potential$ $of$ $the$ $conductor$ and $potential$ $of$ $the$ $conductor$ $at$ $some$ $point$ (may be inside or outside the conductor) are both the different things for which the first
statement only $potential$ $of$ $the$ $conductor$ comes out to be partially wrong because you haven't specified the distance at which we have find the potential.

Comment: In other words the statement "potential of the conductor" makes no sense actually "potential of the conductor at some point" makes sense a lot!

Comment: Please go through all the comments again I hope you will find it easy to understand.

Comment: Okay now I got know that you were asking actually "why does the potential of the ball decreases" that means you were indirectly asking about how does the potential on the surface of the ball decrease in the presence of the negatively charged particle. Is that what you were asking?